# Passing value from form tag to an action method not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with input type `number` and I want to select one number, press Submit and Delete specific row from my database.

The input type looks like this:

```
<input type="number" name="id" value=""/>
```

I'm working with paths and I want to pass that specific value to:

"http://localhost:51206/api/Values/delete/id"

It works when I put some number instead of id. When I press Submit with id value, it says it doesn't work because it is null value.

**Html**

```
<form action="http://localhost:51206/api/Values/delete/id" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            DELETE
            <input type="number" name="id" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        var delete = Connection.dm.Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == id);
        if (delete != null) {
            Connection.dm.Student.Remove(delete);
            Connection.dm.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Ok(Models.db.test);
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills after me choosing number 4 in my form, it says id=4

Comment: why not just change your route to http://localhost:51206/api/Values/delete - you don't want it to be a get for the id anyway (unless you are loading things specific to the id on that page) so you should just pass the whole form model through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `'/id'` from url, simplify it and use `id attribute` in your text box and it will bind.

**View**

```
<form action="api/Values/Delete" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            DELETE
            <input type="number" id="id" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  var delete = Connection.dm.Student.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentID == id);
  if (delete != null) {
      Connection.dm.Student.Remove(delete);
      Connection.dm.SaveChanges();
      }
      return Ok(Models.db.test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add attribute `[HttpPost]` to your method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
```

and remove `id` from form action:

```
<form action="http://localhost:51206/api/Values/delete" method="post">
```

Comment: I already have 1 method that has [HttpPost] attribute so it tells me I have the error.

Comment: A method with the same name `Delete`?

Comment: @ZvonePandza j is right, you should have `[HttpPost]` or...actually...`[HttpDelete]`. `id` shouldn't be part of the path in `action="..."` (and default routing for MVC will map `id` parameter to the last element as required.) In short: do this right and fix any misterious error you may get elsewhere.

Comment: That's not "orthodox" but works. Because html is not restful (you cant pass method="delete" to the form). You can achieve a cleaner result using (ie.) an ajax request as
$.ajax({url: '/api/values', type: 'DELETE' });